# How can I pre-compile the Lua that I pass to luaL_loadbuffer()?

Tags: lua, lua-api

I am using the Lua "C" API function `luaL_loadbuffer()` to run Lua code.

I have a small handful of Lua chunks that I am calling many, many times.  But every time I call `luaL_loadbuffer()` the chunk gets recompiled. This seems hugely inefficient. Most of the code referenced by the chunk is precompiled, but why do I need to recompile the chunk itself every time?  How can I avoid this recompilation?

Can I pass a precompiled chunk to `luaL_loadbuffer()`?

Can I make a full copy of the returned Lua stack and re-use it?

Is there some other clever approach?

Comment: The returned chunk **is** your compiled code. If you want to run it more than once save it and run it again later. Not the stack, the returned chunk itself.

Comment: By "returned chunk" you mean the one that is on the stack yes?  Can I store that an use it on a new (clean) LUA stack?  Or do I need to use the same stack but just make sure I pop everything off it and push that chunk back on?

Comment: Yes, the one on the stack. No, you cannot migrate it to another lua_State. Yes, you can save it in the same lua_State and use it again later. That's lua_State not stack. The (current) stack is a transient thing much of the time. The lua_State is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue to use `luaL_loadbuffer` to load scripts. *Load* here means *precompile*. Just save the function left on the stack somewhere in your program (or leave it on the stack if you can). When the time comes to run a script, `lua_pushvalue` and `lua_pcall` it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `luaL_loadstring` to load the binary chunk you've precompiled with luac. But beware - those binaries are not portable across platforms or Lua versions.

Comment: D'oh!  Yes indeed!  lua_load says this should be possible.  Of course, next question is how do I compile code without using luac (i.e. without having to write my chunk to disk and executing a fork to a subprocess since that's all yucky and a bit fragile).

Comment: If you don't want to use luac, load the source instead, and dump the function object with lua_dump().   It will give you (almost) the same result - you'll have to set the chunk name, etc when you load it back.

Comment: That sounds suitably tricksy!  Any chance of a link to an example code fragment?

Comment: Use `luaL_loadbuffer`, *not* `luaL_loadstring`, because `luaL_loadstring` assumes a zero-ended string.